# How to detect when someone leaves the application?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I have a button that plays a sound in my app. If the user leaves the screen and has the app running in the the background it still plays. How do I detect when the user is outside the app so that I can stop the sound from playing in the background?

**Main Activity Code for current stop button within app**

```
    stop_button = findViewById(R.id.stop_button);
    stop_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (longplay_button.isChecked() &&  meme_Sound_Media_Player.isPlaying()) {
                meme_Sound_Media_Player.pause();
                meme_Sound_Media_Player.seekTo(0);
                longplay_button.setEnabled(true);

            } else if (memeSoundMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                memeSoundMediaPlayer.pause();
                memeSoundMediaPlayer.seekTo(0);
                longplay_button.setEnabled(true);
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "nothing is playing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            if (inactiveButton.isShown()) {
                inactiveButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_pressed);
                inactiveButton.setEnabled(true);
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Playback Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }

        }
    });
```

}

**Error 1**

[image: Error 1]

**Error 2**

[image]

**Current view**
[image]

Comment: Look at `ProcessLifecycleOwner`.

Answer (score 1):

Pull this dependency in your build.gradle file:

```
   dependencies {
   implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1"
  }
```

Then in your Application class, use this:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application implements LifecycleObserver {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    ProcessLifecycleOwner.get().getLifecycle().addObserver(this);
}

@OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP)
private void onAppBackgrounded() {
    Log.d("MyApp", "App in background");
}

@OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_START)
private void onAppForegrounded() {
    Log.d("MyApp", "App in foreground");
}
}
```

Update your AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<application
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    ....>
</application>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'm trying to implement your solution, But I don't know where the build.gradle file is where I should add the first block of code above (I'm new to android).

Comment: Your app builde gradle : here is an example of app builde gradle file :https://docs.coronalabs.com/images/enterprise/as-appBuild3.png

Comment: Ok found it! The only problem that's left is android studio cannot resolve the text in red (I posted in original post)

Comment: Did you implement process lifecycle?

Comment: yes, do I  have to refresh android studio for it to take effect in the gradle? EDIT: just refreshed same errors

Comment: did your class implement LifecycleObserver ?

Comment: Since my class is already implementing  NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, I don't know if I can implement lifecycle observer as well?

Comment: here's  the error I'm getting when I do that posted in the post above (Error 2)

Comment: no , you don't have to add another implement just once and separate them by ","

Comment: implements NavigationView.onNavigationItemSelectedListener ,LifecycleObserver {

Comment: ok just did this, is there something I need to import because lifecycleobserver is red

Comment: no you need only    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1" in your app gradle

Comment: I'm going sync the project files with gradle and restart android studio. To see if it resolves it EDIT: it's  still red, I might be missing something obvious I'm posting the code I'm looking at in the post

Comment: you should extends Application and please look a the code i posted , LifeCycleObserver should be used alone

Comment: Ok I have used everything you have posted verbatim. I can't change the name in the manifest because it conflicts with my main activity class. Instead of nesting the class within the main activity, I put it below the rest of the code outside the main activity class. But if I can't change the name to .MyApplication in the manifest I can't implement this solution.

Comment: no you can change the name of your application in your manifest , its was done for that

Comment: if I do that android studio will say I have a duplicate class

Comment: don't name it MainActivity , name it MyApplication

Comment: Ok so within the application tags in the android manifest change android:name=".MainActivity" to android:name=".MyApplication"?

Comment: Yes and also the name of class that extends  Application and implements LifecycleObserver .... please read my answer carefully

Comment: Yes I have this verbatim public class MyApplication extends Application implements LifecycleObserver { still cannot resolve symbol lifecycle observer

Comment: @ismailalaoui Your answer saved my day.